# Optimizing preg_match() in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, optimization, preg-match

I'm using the following function in PHP to detect an entity and location from strings that contain "near" in it using `preg_match();`. Is there a more optimal way to write the code for this? I'm using a lot of if statements and it seems like it could be improved, but I'm not sure how.

```
// Test cases
$q = "red robin near seattle";
//$q = "red robin near me";
//$q = "red robin nearby";
//$q = "red robin near my location";

function getEntityAndLocation($q){

    $entityAndLocation = array("entity" => null, "location" => null);

    if(preg_match('(nearby)', $q) === 1) {
        $breakdown = explode("nearby", $q);
        $entityAndLocation["entity"] = $breakdown[0];
        $entityAndLocation["location"] = $breakdown[1];
        return $entityAndLocation;
    }

    if(preg_match('(near my location)', $q) === 1) {
        $breakdown = explode("near my location", $q);
        $entityAndLocation["entity"] = $breakdown[0];
        $entityAndLocation["location"] = $breakdown[1];
        return $entityAndLocation;
    }

    if(preg_match('(near me)', $q) === 1) {
        $breakdown = explode("near me", $q);
        $entityAndLocation["entity"] = $breakdown[0];
        $entityAndLocation["location"] = $breakdown[1];
        return $entityAndLocation;
    }

    if(preg_match('(near)', $q) === 1) {
        $breakdown = explode("near", $q);
        $entityAndLocation["entity"] = $breakdown[0];
        $entityAndLocation["location"] = $breakdown[1];
        return $entityAndLocation;
    }

}

if(preg_match('(near)', $q) === 1) {

  $entityAndLocation = getEntityAndLocation($q);

  print_r($entityAndLocation);

}
```

Comment: so you want to see if the string contain a specific "phrase/word"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `preg_split()` to use a a regular expression as a delimiter to split a string. You can write a single regexp that matches all your patterns.

```
function getEntityAndLocation($q){

    $entityAndLocation = array("entity" => null, "location" => null);

    $breakdown = preg_split('/near(?:by| my location| me)?/', $q);
    if (count($breakdown) >= 2) {
        $entityAndLocation["entity"] = $breakdown[0];
        $entityAndLocation["location"] = $breakdown[1];
        return $entityAndLocation;
    }
    return $entityAndLocation;
}
```

The regular expression matches `near`, optionally followed by `by`, `my location`, or `me`.

Comment: Hmm I'm having trouble implementing it.  Did you mean to put  $entityAndLocation = array("entity" => null, "location" => null); before $breakdown? Also, is $1 meant to be $q?

Comment: Yes, this just replaces all the `if` statements, nothing else.

Comment: I'm using your function with "red robin near seattle" and I'm getting an empty array as the ouput. Specifically, Array ( [entity] => [location] => )

Comment: Sorry, typo, `:?` should have been `?:`

Comment: Weird, I changed :? to ?: but I'm still getting an empty $entityAndLocation array

Comment: I forgot the delimiters around the regexp. Didn't you get a warning about that?

Comment: Ah, that fixed it. I'm impressed you can do this stuff off the top of your head. It didn't throw an error, which was strange. Thanks again for your response, and for all the follow up.